# Shopware 6 - Database cluster configuration

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have shop on SW 6 (6.4.17.0). I wanted to add support to multi cluster. I had .env config like that:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://xxxx:xxx@sql01:3306/xxx"
SQL_SET_DEFAULT_SESSION_VARIABLES=0
```

On ma server i have two more nodes. I added configuration:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://xxxx:xxx@sql01:3306/xxx"
DATABASE_REPLICA_0_URL="mysql://xxx:xxx@sql02:3306/xxx"
DATABASE_REPLICA_1_URL="mysql://xxx:xxx@sql03:3306/xxx"
SQL_SET_DEFAULT_SESSION_VARIABLES=0
```

But after that i have 500 error:

```
[2022-11-15T08:46:05.358543+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception TypeError: "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given" at /xxxxxxx/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/FieldSerializer/CustomFieldsSerializer.php line 97 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given at /home/prod/apps/releases/39/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/FieldSerializer/CustomFieldsSerializer.php:97)"} []
```

I have valid SQL configuration:

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+------------+
| @@sql_mode |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
t
mysql> show variables like 'group_concat_max_len';
+----------------------+--------+
| Variable_name        | Value  |
+----------------------+--------+
| group_concat_max_len | 400000 |
+----------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you receive is probably unrelated to the SQL cluster configuration. If the error does not appear if you only use the primary mysql instance i would assume that the mysql replica instances are not synced correctly.

The error suggests that some custom field value in the DB is not correctly filled, so i guess the data inside the mysql instances is not the same in your case. But in general the cluster setup should be configured correctly.

Comment: Okey, but if I use only sql02. That works also like this: `DATABASE_URL="mysql://xxxx:xxx@sql02:3306/xxx"`. Error only appears when i use replicas urls.